# Tikz fit library to include shapes but exclude (cut out) others?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Below is an example using the `fit` library to put a highlight around nodes A, B, and C. What if I wanted to exclude D? (obviously it would have to be a non-rectangular shape)

I guess I'm looking for a way to have union/intersection/difference of shapes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows,positioning,fit,backgrounds,shapes,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,
    block/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum height=6mm, minimum width=30mm,
        rounded corners=1mm,
        node distance=8mm,
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=myblue!15,
        font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
        drop shadow
    },
    area/.style={
        rectangle,
        fill=green!80!black, opacity=0.2,
        draw=black
    },
    >=latex
    ]
        \node (a) {A};
        \node [right=of a] (b) {B};
        \node [below=of a] (c) {C};
        \node [right =of c] (d) {D};
        \node [area, fit=(a) (b) (c)] {};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is similar to [How to perform not rectangular fit with tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230091/how-to-perform-not-rectangular-fit-with-tikz) but not the same.

Comment: See also: [padded boundary of convex hull](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27171/13304) and [Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70999/13304).

Answer (score 3):

See, if the following solution is appropriate to you:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,fit,patterns,positioning,shadows,shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=5mm, 
    auto,
every node/.style={inner sep=2mm, minimum size=7mm}
                        ]
\node (a)               {A};
\node (b) [right=of a]  {B};
\node (c) [below=of a]  {C};
\node (d) [right=of c]  {D};
%
\draw[draw=gray, rounded corners, thick, fill=green!80!black, opacity=0.2]
    (a.north) -| (b.south east) -- (c.south east) -| 
    (a.west) |- (a.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that works in this sample case, but it defeats the point of using the "fit" library. My real problem involves a much more complicated set of shapes.

Comment: I'm afraid, that there not exist a shape, which be appropriate for your needs. So, one solution can be just draw line around selected nodes. In more complex situation, the curve will become more complicated ... some case you can use ellipse, however its positioning is not so simple. In a many cases it can't  avoid some nodes.

Comment: +1 Esp. `|-` and `-|` is useful, would like to know more about this.

Comment: @Ilonpilaaja, see Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, subsection *13.3.1 Intersections of Perpendicular Lines*, page 144 (version 3.1.8b).